# .jar missing in Maven repository

Tags: java, maven

I got a weird issue this morning, which inhibited my development process and since I found the cause, I'd like to hear your opinions on the most sensible move.

My IDE tells me the following dependency from my pom.xml can not be found:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-table</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I couldn't see why, because I can add every other dependency from the repository with no problem, so I looked into the repository, only to find a deserted folder, only containing .pom files! This should also not be a big problem, but the package is not even available in the repository of Apache themselves, the folder is as empty as in the repository I usually use.

What's the deal? Did I find some kind of "forbidden dependency"? Because I start feeling like Nicholas Cage slowly unfolding deep, unnecessary secrets. Is this just a mistake from Apache, which got copied over to the other repositories (I can imagine they are being mirrored, rather than manually updated)?

And most importantly: What are my options here? I would rather avoid to checkout the code from GitHub and compile my own .jar (just like in the old days), if there is any other option. As I'm writing that, I recognize, how much you rely on different tools as a developer, not sure if this is is a good thing, at some point we will be ultimately dependent on such simplification tools, but I think this is another topic for another day.

Comment: Have you try with type?? `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-table</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
`

Comment: Oh wow, that was new to me, as everything I ever included was only ```jar```. Thanks!